# Fetch API cannot load URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request

Tags: javascript, html, localhost

If you only run the html file locally
(**The Fetch API cannot load the URL scheme as "http" or "https" for CORS requests.**) I get an error code like this: How do I try to run it locally without errors?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Teachable Machine Image Model</div>
        <button type="button" onclick="init()">Start</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="predict()">예측</button>
        <script
            class="jsbin"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"
        ></script>
        <div class="file-upload">
            <button
                class="file-upload-btn"
                type="button"
                onclick="$('.file-upload-input').trigger( 'click' )"
            >
                Add Image
            </button>

            <div class="image-upload-wrap">
                <input
                    class="file-upload-input"
                    type="file"
                    onchange="readURL(this);"
                    accept="image/*"
                />
                <div class="drag-text">
                    <h3>Drag and drop a file or select add Image</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="file-upload-content">
                <img class="file-upload-image" id="face-image" src="#" alt="your image" />
                <div class="image-title-wrap">
                    <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove-image">
                        Remove <span class="image-title">Uploaded Image</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="webcam-container"></div>
        <div id="label-container"></div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.3.1/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/image@0.8/dist/teachablemachine-image.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('.image-upload-wrap').hide();

                        $('.file-upload-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
                        $('.file-upload-content').show();

                        $('.image-title').html(input.files[0].name);
                    };

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                } else {
                    removeUpload();
                }
            }

            function removeUpload() {
                $('.file-upload-input').replaceWith($('.file-upload-input').clone());
                $('.file-upload-content').hide();
                $('.image-upload-wrap').show();
            }
            $('.image-upload-wrap').bind('dragover', function () {
                $('.image-upload-wrap').addClass('image-dropping');
            });
            $('.image-upload-wrap').bind('dragleave', function () {
                $('.image-upload-wrap').removeClass('image-dropping');
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // More API functions here:
            // https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/image

            const URL = './my_model/';
            let model, labelContainer, maxPredictions;

            async function init() {
                const modelURL = URL + 'model.json';
                const metadataURL = URL + 'metadata.json';
                model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
                maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();


                labelContainer = document.getElementById('label-container');
                for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
                    // and class labels
                    labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    <!-- Copyright (c) 2021 by Aaron Vanston (https://codepen.io/aaronvanston/pen/yNYOXR)
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE. -->
</html>
```

The code is (license included.)

1. Please tell me the permission to use it on localhost, not http or https.
2. Please tell me this permission how to do how to make the model with hdf5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to run a local web server. Do you have node installed? Almost everyone does these days but if not, follow the directions here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Then create an `index.html` file and paste in the above code. Open a terminal, navigate to the directory with your index file and type `npx serve`. This will fetch https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve and run a tiny web server.

The URL for the index file will be coped to your clipboard. Open your browser, paste the link, and you should see the file.